# Out[ ] cells suddenly begin with newline

Tags: output

This is a "feature" of Mathematica that persists through several versions.
What happens: Mathematica experiences some internal hiccup and from then on starts every Out[ ] cell with a newline, which is extremely annoying. I tried to figure out how to cancel this behavior; so far the only thing that helps is exiting and restarting Mathematica, and it helps only up to the next unexplainable hiccup... Has anybody else experienced this? If yes, has anybody found a way of canceling the unwanted leading newlines in Out[ ] cells, without exiting and restarting Mathematica?

Here is a screenshot requested by QuantumDot:

[image: Leading newline in Out: cell]

Comment: What do you mean "starts every Out: cell with a newline".  Can you post screenshot when it happens again?

Comment: You should provide version number(s) and OS. Have you searched the site for similar questions yet (this kind of sounds familiar).

Comment: @Yves Klett - Matematica 9.0.1.0, Windows 7. But, as I said, this "feature" has persisted through a series of Windows OS and at least since Mathematica 4, which was the first version of Mathematica I used. Just after I typed in the title of the question I looked through the list of suggested possibly similar questions, but no question was about this particular "feature".

Comment: Which language or localization are you using?  Do you have any specialized font or accessibility settings turned on?

Comment: @Mr Wizard - I am not sure I know what you are asking. Language: is this the keyboard language? If it is, it is Englush (United kingdom). What is localization? I am not aware of using specialized fonts or having any accesibility settings turned on. As I already said, more than once, this "feature" of Mathematica has been with me through a series of Windows OS and versions of Mathematica, so its cause is almost surely not in some arcane settings.

Comment: That is all I was asking.  I seem to recall that a few Chinese users have had problems that only affected them for example.  I wish I could help but I don't think I've seen this problem before.  Have you ever contacted offical Support over this issue?

Comment: Does this happen in a new notebook, or only in an older one that you re-opened? I'm thinking of possibly corrupted style definitions (just speculation at this point).

Comment: @Mr Wizard - No, I have not contacted official Support, for the simple reason that I haven't known such an august body exists. How do I contanct official Support?

Comment: @Jens - It happens in a fresh notebook as well as in a reopened notebook. The problem with this feature is that it cannot be reproduced at will, since it always appears without any apparent reason. For example, it does not appear because I by mistake (pressing Ctrl instead of Shift, say) entered a magic key sequence that activates/toggles the insertion of the leading newline into the output cell. (Humm - perchance there really exists a front end command which does this?)

Comment: Try http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/ but not all licenses have the same length or level of support from WRI.  To be clear I was not trying to make you go somewhere else; I really wondered if they had any comment on this peculiar annoyance.  Sadly *Mathematica* has for years had a few more bugs than many of us would like but it does enough things uniquely well that many also learn to overlook them.

Comment: Sorry, it may indeed by something for Wolfram support. One more thing to try: does it make a difference if you change the option `Preferences > Advanced > Notebook Options > Display Option > Magnification` to a different value? Or in that same pane, go from Printing to Working Style environment or vice versa...